# How to append dictionary to DataFrame as a row?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I want to append dictionary to DataFrame, but in this dictionary I dont have any index value.
I also need to remove everything except "1393" from 'KP' value.
This looks like this:

To this df:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylpFo.png)

I want to append dictionary like this:

```
dict = {'KP': [1.0    1393
  Name: KP, dtype: int64],
 'Wiek': [Timedelta('176 days 12:59:43.042156102')],
 'KY1': [113.0],
 'OKO': [57.51],
 'GS': [10.59],
 'T': [654.31],
 'MP': [58.9]}
```

I try this:

```py
df.append(dict,ignore_index=True)
```

But nothing happend, df is still the same and i dont get any error.
I try to convert this dictionary to list and append list as row to df but I got the same result.

Ok i try this:

```py
df = df.append(dict, ignore_index = True)
```

I get this output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WMHD.png)

This is not good enought i need clear data.

Comment: Use `df = df.append(dict, ignore_index = True)`.

Comment: You can convert the dictionary into a dataframe: `df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict)` and then append: `df = df.append(df1, ignore_index = True)`. Btw using `dict` as a variable name is highly non-recomended as dict is a built-in keyword; also please never post images of dataframes, post them as text as explained in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: You can use `df.loc[len(df)] = dict`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76132725/19123103).

Answer (score 9):

As the 'append' method is deprecated, you may need to consider to use 'concat':

```
the_dict = {'k1':'v1','k2':'v2'}
df_the_dict = pd.DataFrame({'name':the_dict.keys(), 'value':the_dict.values()})

df_final = pd.concat([df_final, df_the_dict], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I find adding rows to Pandas unbelievably unelegant un unpythonic. I cannot believe that the append method was dropped, which was intuitive and which would accept dictionaries.

Comment: it's unreal. Concat to add a row? Come on.

Comment: Yes @vega, I have a table and want to add a row. Natural way of storing a row is as a dict. Doing this mambo jumbo with concat is counter-intuitive. Why are you not doing this with lists? Instead of [].append(item), you could do newlist = [] + [item]. Better?

Comment: @Paloha in some situations you need to stick with dataframes. I think it's nuts they dropped `append()`. Creating a new dataframe by concatenation every time you want to just add a row is really unpythonic.

Comment: @vega from your comment before I thought you were advocating for it. Now I see we agree. Yes, also in my opinion it is unpythonic.