# How to append 1 row to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file which I read into a pandas DataFrame.

File A:

```
2009,7,1,3,101,13.03,89.33,0.6,287.69,0
2009,7,1,6,102,19.3,55,1,288.67,0
2009,7,1,9,103,22.33,39.67,1,289.6,0
2009,7,1,12,104,21.97,41,1,295.68,0
```

Read this into a DataFrame

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from datetime import datetime as dtdt
>>> par3 = lambda x: dtdt.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H')
>>> df3=pd.read_csv('fileA.txt',header=None,parse_dates={'Date': [0,1,2,3]}, date_parser=par3, index_col='Date')
>>> df3
                       4      5      6    7       8  9
Date                                                  
2009-07-01 03:00:00  101  13.03  89.33  0.6  287.69  0
2009-07-01 06:00:00  102  19.30  55.00  1.0  288.67  0
2009-07-01 09:00:00  103  22.33  39.67  1.0  289.60  0
2009-07-01 12:00:00  104  21.97  41.00  1.0  295.68  0
```

Then, I have new data to be appended into df3 as a new row

```
bb = '2009-07-01 15:00:00'
cc = '105 18.11 44.55 1.2 300.12 0'
```

**Question** how do I append this new row to get

```
>>> new_df3
                       4      5      6    7       8  9
Date                                                  
2009-07-01 03:00:00  101  13.03  89.33  0.6  287.69  0
2009-07-01 06:00:00  102  19.30  55.00  1.0  288.67  0
2009-07-01 09:00:00  103  22.33  39.67  1.0  289.60  0
2009-07-01 12:00:00  104  21.97  41.00  1.0  295.68  0
2009-07-01 15:00:00  105  18.11  44.55  1.2  300.12  0
```

This [How to append dictionary to DataFrame as a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70890443/how-to-append-dictionary-to-dataframe-as-a-row) did not work in my case, I get either messy results or error messages.

I am aware of the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html,
(join): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join
(merge): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge
but my head already has pretty much exploded. Solution would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe something like `row = {"Date": bb}row.update(dict(zip(range(4, 9), cc.split())); df3.append(row)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas indexer can make row or column

```
df.loc[bb] = c.split()
```